# Xamarin.Forms - Shell Initially Doesn't Reflect Color Properties

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Shell in Xamarin.Forms that I've set the Attached Properties (for color) for:

```
<Shell x:Class="Sample.MyApp.Views.MasterView"
       xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
       xmlns:behavior="clr-namespace:Sample.MyApp.Behaviors"
       xmlns:definitions="clr-namespace:Sample.MyApp.Definitions"
       xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Sample.MyApp.Views"
       Shell.BackgroundColor="{x:Static definitions:Colors.ShellBackgroundColor}"
       Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor="{x:Static definitions:Colors.ShellBackgroundColor}"
       Shell.TabBarForegroundColor="{x:Static definitions:Colors.ShellForegroundColor}"
       Shell.TitleColor="{x:Static definitions:Colors.ShellForegroundColor}"
       Shell.UnselectedColor="{x:Static definitions:Colors.BlockForegroundMutedColor}">
```

And this works great -- but only after I navigate somewhere else (which can sometimes be confusing).  In iOS, the Shell Background is white (as is the flyout menu's icon), and in Android, it is a slight blue.

Once I navigate to another page, everything renders as it should -- no problems.

Is there something wrong with this method of setting the colors on the Shell?

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent(); 
    MainPage = new MasterView() { BindingContext = new MasterViewModel() };
}
```

This is the constructor for the App (re: Xamarin.Forms.Application).

Is there another method of setting Shell colors that I'm missing?

[image: Problematic Issue]

[image]

(Android, then iOS) The left side is what "initially" loads.  When I navigate to any page, it gets the correct color scheme (on the right).  I swap sections and then go back -- and then my color is correct.

In iOS this is even worse, because the background color is WHITE, so you cannot see any of the items in the Header.

Comment: I set the shell background color to green. It works well. You could check the screenshot. https://imgur.com/khaJ4wg I am confused about your description. Do you get the wrong bacground color? Could you provide more xaml code with what the color should be and what the color is now?

Comment: Wendy, I've updated the original post -- look at the screenshot difference.  The left is how it loads (and on iOS, the "blue" is all white -- so you can't see the menu or title).  When I navigate away, it starts taking the correct color (screenshot on right).  I'm not sure if there's something in the individual platform-dependent apps that needs to be configured, perhaps, which handles the "default" colors for the shell?

Comment: I try to reproduce, but on my test, it could loads well when i use the code in AppShell.cs `Shell.BackgroundColor="Accent"`. You could check the image. https://imgur.com/qH1KPom I think it caused by how to defined the color. Could you provide more code about this?

Comment: So, I figured out the issue.  I'm dynamically assembling the ShellContent (I have a behavior that reflects over some navigation items [internal class]).  When I create the Shell Content, I'm setting the Shell.<insert property> on it and it works perfectly fine.  Unfortunately, it requires me to have the ShellBackgroundColor, etc, defined on both the Shell and the ContentPages to work.

Comment: I am glad to help you find what cause the error. If you do not mind, i will post in the answer.